# Equivalent of Python urllib in Haskell

Tags: python, haskell, urllib2

Is there an equivalent of Python's urllib library in Haskell? I want to login into course homepage (on Moodle) and download assignments automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend [http-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit); it's widely-used, has a simple interface and an efficient implementation, plus [automation for multi-page request flows](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-conduit/latest/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Conduit-Browser.html) (including cookies, etc.).

A more standard option (part of the Haskell Platform) is the [HTTP](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP) library, which has [similar automation support](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/latest/doc/html/Network-Browser.html), but personally, I prefer http-conduit's API.

Comment: I find it odd that `http-conduit` doesn't seem to support enumerators, but I thought it was supposed to replace `http-enumerator` (another excellent option)

Comment: @monadic: http-conduit uses [conduits](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit), the alternative to enumerators from the same author.